# Convert an Array, converted to a String, back to an Array

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I recently found an interesting behaviour in python due to a bug in my code.
Here's a simplified version of what happened:

```
a=[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
print(str(a))
```

```
console:
"[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]"
```

Now I wondered if I could convert the String back to an Array.Is there a good way of converting a String, representing an Array with mixed datatypes( `"[1,'Hello',['test','3'],True,2.532]"`) including integers,strings,booleans,floats and arrays back to an Array?

Comment: I hope you're aware the other question you found is for a completely different programming language, and the code in it wouldn't work at all in Python.

Comment: @ user2357112 Oh,thanks. Totally missed that. I'll remove the reference

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's always everybody's old favourite `ast.literal_eval`

```
>>> import ast
>>> x = "[1,'Hello',['test','3'],True,2.532]"
>>> y = ast.literal_eval(x)
>>> y
[1, 'Hello', ['test', '3'], True, 2.532]
>>> z = str(y)
>>> z
"[1, 'Hello', ['test', '3'], True, 2.532]"
```

Answer (score 4):

ast.literal_eval is better. Just to mention, this is also a way.

```
a=[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
string_list = str(a)
original_list = eval(string_list)
print original_list == a
# True
```

Comment: I come from the future, there is no reason to use this in a situation like this.